# Ensuring uniform style between List of Figures and List of Algorithms in tufte-book

Tags: tufte

In a tufte-book in TeXShop, I'm using

```
\usepackage[ ]{algorithm2e}
```

and call with code in the body of the book, such as:

```
\color{blue}
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{
\color{black}
\begin{algorithm}[H] \label{alg:scanning}
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{Scanning}
\end{algorithm}
}
\color{black}
```

Then I create a *List of algorithms* using

```
\listofalgorithms
```

and get typeset output such as:

[image: List of Algorithms]

Notice the style:  dotted lines to right-justified page numbers.

Instead, I'd like the style to be identical to that in the automatic and analogous creation of the *List of figures* (no dotted lines; no right-justified page numbers):

[image: List of Figures]

How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe `\makeatletter \let\l@algocf\l@figure \makeatother`?

Comment: Yep!  Didn't know that function.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment.